# Html is rendered event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm appending some code to my page using jQuery AJAX calls. This code is a mix of html and javascript. But I want javascript to be executed only when html part is ready. But what event is raised when appended html is rendered?

Here is an example:

```
<table id="sampleTable">
   ...
</table>

<script>
  // this code should be executed only when sampleTable is rendered
  $('#sampleTable').hide();
</script>
```

Comment: when you say HTML part is ready, is the HTML being returned from the AJAX call and then being inserted into the DOM and you want some JavaScript to run when that insertion has taken place? Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. But JavaScript is returned from the AJAX call too.

Answer (score 6):

Use the jQuery ready() event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sampleTable').hide();
}
```

`<edit>` It seems to be impossible to call a ready event on any other object than Document, my bad `</edit>`

This is an option if you are talking about the event triggered after a successful Ajax request :

```
$('#sampleTable').ajaxComplete(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Or just hardcode the style of the table to display:none;...

Comment: And what if it is ready before I have subscribed to "ready" event?

Comment: @tvanfosson: That's not the same i guess? He uses sampleTable.ready, the shortcut is document.ready - if this is even possible, never heard of it before :D

Comment: @Mef - Yeah. I didn't look at it closely enough - just cut/paste my comment from another answer. The ready event only applies to the DOM (document), not specific elements. I'd use the DOM ready event handler. For a specific element, you'd need to use "load" -- which is slightly different.

Comment: Yes, you guys are right, I edited the answer to reflect the comments, and added the 'ready' like event for Ajax requests.

Comment: @ldsa: it's a tricky one. Some browsers do not want to execute any javascript before the loading of the page is ready, while others execute when they encounter it. This is why the $(document).ready() event was created: to not fire any events until the dom is complete and ready to be manipulated. Why don't you just hardcode the style of the table to display:none; ?

Comment: @Powertieke: Yes, that's what I have finally done :) Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your javascript in a "ready" handler.  This will fire when the DOM has been updated and is undoubtedly what you want to do.

```
 $(function() {
     $('#sampleTable').hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sampleTable').hide();    
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I prefer the short-cut `$(function() { ... });`

Comment: I don't. I use bind('the-event') as well. Guess I'm special!

Comment: @Matt - I just got tired of all the extra typing to no purpose. Also, I hope that the ready event hasn't actually fired by the time it reaches your code if you use `bind('ready',...)`

Comment: @tvanfosson: I use $(document).ready(), then bind for everything else. Especially with the recent introductions of live and delegate, I feel it makes your code much more consistent, readable and understandable. I guess the typing will get to me eventually... Then I'll take all this back :P

Answer (score 1):

You're loading both the `<table>` and the `<script>` into the document at once? *Don't*.

Inserting HTML with `<script>` elements into the page using `html()`/`load()` is highly unreliable. The script doesn't run directly from `innerHTML` inclusion; different browsers treat such inserted script elements differently. jQuery attempts to fix some of this but doesn't quite get it quite right (it may not be possible to get it quite right).

It's best to keep your static code in static script, so that the caller knows it has to call `hide()` on the table just after the AJAX call completes and the content is inserted. If you really *have* to pass back dynamic code to run, keep it separate from the HTML, eg. by returning a JSON object with both HTML and code members.